# Where on a collection

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query

```
MATCH (r)-[a*]->(b)
```

and i would like to add something to the effect of

```
WHERE a.someAttribute = 1
```

but I can't since a is a collection. Is there any good way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ALL` the relationships should have this property with the value, you can use the `ALL` predicate :

```
MATCH (r)-[a*]->(b)
WHERE ALL (x IN a WHERE x.someAttribute = 1)
```

You can also use a shorter version and specify the attribute inline :

```
MATCH (r)-[a* {someAttribute: 1}]->(b)
```

If on the other hand, only a single relationship should have this value, you can use `ANY`:

```
MATCH (r)-[a*]->(b)
WHERE ANY (x IN a WHERE x.someAttribute = 1)
```